# Node Red Error Message (certificate has expired)

Tags: database, node-red

i am relative new to node red, so i am not sure how to resolve this Problem. When I try to deploy a Postresql node, I get a "Error: certificate has expired" Message. I'm not sure if this is important but at User and Password, I used the respective Username and Password from Server i want to send the Data to.

Comment: Assuming that the date is right on the Node-RED machine, the solution is likely to be, renew the certificate on the postgres server

Comment: How can I renew a certificate for my postgres server?

Comment: That's a question for the postgres community